# Copy sources files into target directory with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I recently decided to use SBT to build an existing project. 
In this project I have some .glsl files within the scala packages which I need to copy during the compilation phase.

The project is structured like this :

```
- myapp.opengl
   - Shader.scala
- myapp.opengl.shaders
   - vertex_shader.glsl
   - fragment_shader.glsl
```

Is this file structure correct for SBT or do I need to put the .glsl files into an other directory. And do you know a clean way to copy these files into the target folder ?

*I would prefer not putting these files into the resources directory since they are (non-compiled) sources files*

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not recommend putting those files into `src/main/scala` as they do not belong there. If you want to keep them separate from your resource files, you can put them in a custom path, e.g. `src/main/glsl` and add the following lines to your project definition to have them copied into output directory:

```
val shaderSourcePath = "src"/"main"/"glsl"

// use shaderSourcePath as root path, so directory structure is
// correctly preserved (relative to the source path)
def shaderSources = (shaderSourcePath ##) ** "*.glsl"

override def mainResources = super.mainResources +++ shaderSources
```

Comment: @Mr_Qqn I have a kind of same requirement for my Java project and I am unable to figure out which project config file for sbt do we need to make the changes to (Plus I do not have any experience with Scala as well)

Comment: Can you do the same thing with webappResources? I know there's a webappPath variable that you can change but I can't find any mention of a webappResources that could be used to merge resources from multiple folders.

Comment: Which file does this go in?

Comment: "override def mainResources" does not seem to be accepted by build.sbt. What should one do when using build.sbt, not build.scala?